# Adding python to PATH system variable still does not prevent 'pip' from not being recognized

Tags: python, pip, psychopy

I understand that this issue arises when you have not added the python path to the PATH system variable. However, I have added the path of the python executable to the PATH system variable (as when I installed python there is no python folder that has been installed onto my computer). After doing this, I am still not able to install psychopy using pip, as I am getting the same error as before.

Comment: share the error you are having

Comment: You say `I have added the path of the python executable to the PATH system variable`.  Do you mean that you've added the path to the directory that contains the Python executable?  That's what you want to do.  If you added the path of the actual Python executable, that won't help your system find `pip`.  If you did do that right and added the path to the directory, is there an executable named `pip` in that directory?

Comment: It's the "pip install psychopy not recognized as an internal or external command" error.

Comment: Steve - yes, that's what I've done. There is no pip where the executable is found. In that directory I'm only seeing four things. Just IDLE, Python 3.9 Manuals, Python 3.9 Module Docs, and the Python executable.